# Is the sentence 'What I need is to do/doing the things I like.' grammatically correct?

Tags: clauses, infinitive-vs-gerund, subordinate-clauses

There is a task in Oxford English Grammar (Basic) by Michael Swan and Catherine Walter that goes as follows: Write a sentence beginning 'What I need is...' Which made me think of which is more preferable - 'the infinitive' or the '-ing form' after the main clause and why?

I am also interested in what this structure is properly called.

Any reference sources are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the pattern

`What I need is...` + {some needed *action*}  [rather than some needed *thing*]

the complement will be an infinitive clause necessarily headed by "to", and the verb will express the idea of "acquire".

> ... to get some sleep.

If the action needed is some action you yourself must *perform*, then it goes like this:

> What I need *to do* is ...

and the complement remains an infinitive clause but now optionally headed by "to", and the verb will express the idea of "perform":

> ... (to) tell them we cannot be there on Thursday.

P.S. You can also complement **needs** with an -ing form of the verb:

> What she needs is coaching.
>
> What the barn needs is painting.

She needs to be coached. The barn needs to be painted.  The underlying verb must be transitive when the intended meaning is `what must be done to the subject of the verb NEED`.  This would be ungrammatical:

> What she needs is trying harder. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

P.P.S. There are some verbs which occupy a gray middle area between transitive and intransitive:

> What a good stew needs is simmering.
>
> For this icing the chocolate needs melting.

The stew needs to simmer. The stew needs to be simmered.

The chocolate needs to melt. The chocolate needs to be melted.

Some of those verbs no longer have an intransitive infinitive when an inanimate object is the subject of NEED:

> The fence needs repairing.

The fence needs to repair.<sup>archaic</sup>  The fence needs to be repaired.

But we can say:

> The body needs to repair and rebuild.

Comment: Is it possible to use the '-ing form' in the sentence above and if yes - what meaning will it convey?

Comment: Please see the P.S.

Comment: Does this structure have a special/proper name?

Comment: I don't know. These are characterisitcs of the verb NEED.

Comment: What about the sentence 'What I need is travelling.' Can the '-ing form' here be perceived as a noun as in 'What I need is the sun/a good company.'?

Comment: I think *What I need is traveling* is a marginal case. We have the noun **travel**. *What I need is travel.*  It would also be idiomatic to say *What I need to do is (to) travel*.

Comment: Are you sure you can't say _What I need is to travel._?

Comment: @listeneva:  You could say "What I need is to travel" just as you could say  "What I need is to start saving my money".  You would certainly be understood. But other constructions would be much more idiomatic.   Very very few native speakers would say either of those things. In those cases, and cases like them, most native speakers would say "What I need *to do* is..."  What I need to do is (to) travel.  What I need to do is (to) start saving my money.